# Android navigation view inflate exception on API 19

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

My app is working fine on latest API but when i try to run it on Kit Kat API 19 it starting crash with following exception

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

And on line 17 of xml file i have

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent" -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

Exception:

```
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): Process: com.app.myapp, PID: 3356
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myapp/com.app.myapp.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.app.myapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:66)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     ... 11 more
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     ... 22 more
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200cc
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:321)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:495)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:245)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
06-09 17:25:53.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: Do you have support libraries integrated? Also can you share the entire crash log?

Comment: please have a look on crash log.thanks

Comment: does the header of the layout file have the app namespace declaration?

Comment: yes, i have updated layout section please have a look.

Comment: Pay attention to `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200cc` Try to rebuild the apk. Do you use dexguard or proguard? Does it work on SDK > 19?

Comment: Please try to add LinearLayout around your `app_bar_home`

Comment: i tried to add LinearLayout  around LinearLayout but it didn't worked for me. thanks

Comment: I think you are missing the support libraries. Do you have this in your gradle ? compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' ?

Comment: yes i have support libraries