# Inflate NavigationView causes exception in Android 4.4 and lower

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

So I have the same problem as [this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736536/android-navigation-view-inflate-exception-on-api-19), but since nobody answered him, I wanted to provide some more context to see if we can figure this out. I've been looking for an answer for this for a while now and nothing that worked.

I'm implementing some Material Design widgets in my app, such as NavigationView, TabLayout and Cards. These are the support libraries I'm compiling (updated them today):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
```

Target and min SDK:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 24
```

This is where I'm using the navigation view:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
...
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           .../>
       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nav_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
       app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.mariano.numberreflexgame, PID: 5006
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mariano.numberreflexgame/com.mariano.numberreflexgame.OpeningMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                            at com.mariano.numberreflexgame.OpeningMenu.onCreate(OpeningMenu.java:109)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at com.mariano.numberreflexgame.OpeningMenu.onCreate(OpeningMenu.java:109) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02009f
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:313)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:422)
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:475)
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:246)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:170)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:96)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at com.mariano.numberreflexgame.OpeningMenu.onCreate(OpeningMenu.java:109) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

From some other answers I saw, this is the theme the activity in question is applying:

```
<style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The app works great in Android 5.0 but crashes in 100% of the devices with Android 4.4 I've tested in.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: One of the resource ID is missing As log shows check all of them, It's not related to Kitkat or Lolipop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have some menu icons in res/drawable-v21 folder but don't have them in res/drawable folder.

**Update:**

You can find the "problem" resource by its id (#0x7f02009f) in the file
app/build/generated/source/r/debug (or release)/you/package/id/R.java

Comment: This was absolutely it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't have 15 reputation yet so can't upvote you, but you are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoMolina no problem, glad to help you